# Why we use (null) while creating dropdown in react js?

Tags: reactjs

if we have not put null then it gives parsing error.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div  className="dropdown" style = {{background:"Red",width:"2000px"}} >
      <div className="button" onClick={this.showDropdownMenu}> User Info</div>
      {this.state.displayMenu ? (
        <ul>
         <li><a className="active" href="#Orders">Orders</a></li>
         <li><a href="#Payment Details">Payment Details</a></li>
         <li><a href="#Your Address">Your Address</a></li>
         <li><a href="#Your Profile">Profile</a></li>
         <li><a href="#Activity">Activity</a></li>
         <li><a href="#Setting">Setting</a></li>
         <li><a href="#Log Out">Log Out</a></li>
       </ul>
      ):
      (
        null
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: See here: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#preventing-component-from-rendering

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to add null don't use ternary, you can do this:

```
 render() { 
    return (

      <div className="dropdown" style = {{background:"Red",width:"2000px"}} >
         <div className="button" onClick={this.showDropdownMenu}> User Info</div>

           { this.state.displayMenu && (
            <ul>
             <li><a className="active" href="#Orders">Orders</a></li>
             <li><a href="#Payment Details">Payment Details</a></li>
             <li><a href="#Your Address">Your Address</a></li>
             <li><a href="#Your Profile">Profile</a></li>
             <li><a href="#Activity">Activity</a></li>
             <li><a href="#Setting">Setting</a></li>
             <li><a href="#Log Out">Log Out</a></li>
            </ul>
            )}

      </div>
     );
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should always return a value from an expression. Even if the value it's `null`. To avoid `ternary operators` when you have a `boolean` you could render like this

```
return condition && <JSX />
```

Answer (score 1):

For the case that `this.state.displayMenu` is false, you return `null` to preventing a component from rendering. In your case it's explicitly set to null.

React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#preventing-component-from-rendering

> In rare cases you might want a component to hide itself even though it was rendered by another component. To do this return null instead of its render output.